# FreeRTOS stack size too small? I'm getting stack overflow

Tags: stack-overflow, freertos

I am using *FreeRTOS* and i want to use mac protocol which i made !

On a single task, I want to `Send_Beacon()` function(send beacon frame).

When i call that function in task, there was a stack overflow.

```
void vApplicationStackOverflowHook(TaskHandle_t pxTask, char *pcTaskName)
```

vApplicationStackOverflowHook was called.

```
if (xTaskCreate(MAC_Init, (signed portCHAR *)"MAC_Inits", 128, NULL, 3,
        NULL) == pdTRUE) {
    //GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_C_BASE,GPIO_PIN_3,GPIO_PIN_3);
}
```

I had tried to change stack depth parameter from 128 to 1600.

It was failed.

What is the problem ?

Is not a problem about stack depth parameter's value ?

Answer (score 1):

Remember the stack size is specified in words, not bytes.  See the documentation of the [xTaskCreate()](http://www.freertos.org/a00125.html) and [xTaskCreateStatic()](http://www.freertos.org/xTaskCreateStatic.html) functions.

If you are using xTaskCreate(), and cannot create the task after increasing its stack size, then you are running out of [FreeRTOS heap](http://www.freertos.org/a00111.html) (the link tells you what to do about it).

Comment: Cannot creat the task after increasing its stack size means cannot change or handle  size of stack when i use xTaskCreate?

Answer (score 0):

To look for stack overflow, or risk of a potential future stack overflow, and to see if your stack is large enough, use the functions `uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark()`, `uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark2()`, `vTaskList()`, and `vTaskListTasks()`.

See details on these functions and usage here:

1. https://www.freertos.org/uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark.html
2. https://www.freertos.org/a00021.html#vTaskList
3. My answer: [FreeRTOS: obtain the stack size (`usStackDepth`) value in words or bytes after calling `xTaskCreate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77568267/4561887)